# Unable to read input type array values in next page in php

Tags: php, mysql

My First Page:

```
<form name="f1" method="post" action="next.php">
<?php
                    $result = $linkID1->query("select group_name,created_by,member_email,test_topic,joined_status,exam_name,your_score from cae_group_test where group_name='$gname' order by your_score desc")
or
die("error");
                    $exam_name=$row['exam_name'];
                    $_SESSION['exam_name']=$exam_name;

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                ?>
<select name="rewards[]">
  <option selected value="Select Reward Point">Select Reward Point</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>
 <input name="member_email[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['member_email']; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="FINISH TEST" >

}
?>
</form>
```

next.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$rewards = $_POST['rewards'];
$member_email = $_POST['member_email'];

$limit = count($rewards);

for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++) 
{
        $rewards[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($rewards[$i]);
        $member_email[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($member_email[$i]);

        echo "Rewards : ".$rewards[$i];
        echo "<br>Member Email : ".$member_email[$i];
}
?>
```

But next.php page is ending with error. The page doesn't execute. I can't read the values of rewards and member_email of the candidates. I can't get the error.

Error --

```
This page isn’t working

mywebsite.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Comment: just print $rewards and $member_email

Comment: What are you expecting the page to do? It seems like there's nothing being displayed or done. If you can't get the error what makes you think there is an error?

Comment: @iCoders.............print $rewards and $member_email -- not working

Comment: @SidTheBeard...............while printing the output i am getting the error

Comment: @JahangirAlam: ok, but since WE CANNOT SEE YOUR SCREEN, what is the error?  Append it to the bottom of your question.

Comment: HAHAHA...........i asked the question.........i solved it and somebody gave my question DOWNVOTE...........if u don't know the answer then just ignore it don't waste your valuable time to DOWNVOTE as i ignored YOU.

Answer (score 0):

Remove [] from the input elements as it seems that your are submitting single value. Since your dropdown element does not contain multiple attribute and second your hidden element also submit string value although you define name of hidden element as member_email[].
If you want multiple values then code would be as
First page code :

```
<?php
```

`$row['member_email'] = 'xyz@gmail.com';`
`?>`

```
<form name="f1" method="post" action="next.php">
<select name="rewards[]" multiple>
  <option selected value="Select Reward Point">Select Reward Point</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>
 <input name="member_email[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['member_email']; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="FINISH TEST" >
</form>
```

And second page code as :

```
<?php
session_start();
$rewards = $_POST['rewards'];
$member_email = $_POST['member_email'];

var_dump($_POST);exit;
```

Comment: I am using multiple values, pls see my edited question now. Thanks

Comment: In second page , below session_start , write  var_dump($_POST);exit;  check any error coming or not.

Comment: This output is coming ----
array(2) { ["rewards"]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(2) "50" [1]=> string(2) "50" [2]=> string(2) "50" [3]=> string(2) "10" [4]=> string(2) "10" [5]=> string(1) "5" [6]=> string(1) "5" [7]=> string(1) "5" [8]=> string(1) "5" [9]=> string(1) "5" } ["member_email"]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(17) "farhu22@gmail.com" [1]=> string(27) "jahangiralam.work@gmail.com" [2]=> string(15) "hirak@gmail.com" [3]=> string(16) "dhiman@gmail.com" [4]=> string(15) "rupak@gmail.com" [5]=> string(17) "gunajit@gmail.com" [6]=> string(15) "rupam@gmail.com" ........... }

Comment: remove mysql_real_escape_string from the code.  Hope your code will run correctly

Answer (score 0):

Finally, solved my problem---

Just removed the line --

```
$rewards[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($rewards[$i]);
$member_email[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($member_email[$i]);
```

from next.php file. And all goes well. Thanks guyz